# Can I use String[] as HashMap values in Java?

Tags: java, string, dictionary

I am a beginner in Java programming. I want to create a HashMap whose values are String[]'s.

Suppose I have a `JTable parametersTable` with values in columns 2, 3, and 4 that I wish to fetch from each row. Each three-value set constitutes a `HashMap` value (`String[]`).

```
HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
String[] row = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven","eight","nine","ten","eleven"};
for (int i=0; i<row.length; i++) {
map.put(row[i], new String[] {
   (String) parametersTable.getValueAt(i, 2),
   (String) parametersTable.getValueAt(i, 3),
   (String) parametersTable.getValueAt(i, 4)});
}
System.out.println(map);
```

The above code outputs:

`{nine=[Ljava.lang.String;@187930f1, six=[Ljava.lang.String;@2a8000ab, four=[Ljava.lang.String;@4436b0fd, one=[Ljava.lang.String;@134bc965, seven=[Ljava.lang.String;@42e49d45, eleven=[Ljava.lang.String;@68cb58ea, ten=[Ljava.lang.String;@198bbc56, two=[Ljava.lang.String;@54464ee3, three=[Ljava.lang.String;@32aeff9b, five=[Ljava.lang.String;@90ed2c, eight=[Ljava.lang.String;@443d9864}`

Why is the output something cryptic and not the values like I expect?

Comment: Yes you can. What is the challenge you are facing?

Comment: You might also consider the use of a guava Multimap.  http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v17.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: You can use any sort of object as the value for a hashmap.

Comment: I would consider using a `List<String>` instead, but that's just me

Comment: The use of a `Map` in this context (for a `JTable`) doesn't really make sense (to me), you would actually be better to use a `List<String[]>` or `List<List<String>>` - IMHO

Comment: @Juned Ahsan The code above compiles, but it doesn't print the actual values from the cell like I expect. Instead of getting the cell values, I get something kind of cryptic like `java.something, .234567` for my values. Not sure if that helps. I can elaborate by checking the exact output later today.

Comment: Your problem is, that .toString() on String[] does not print what you want. But the storing and retrieving works. Yo ucan use `java.util.Arrays.toString(String[])`. BTW: it is not so cryptic, it will print `[` for Array, then the type (`I` is integer and objects print the type as `Lpackage.Class;`. In your case String) and then the system hashcode of the array object after the `@`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the output something cryptic and not the values like I expect?

`[Ljava.lang.String;@` is the default representation of String arrays toString() method.

Use `Arrays.toString` method instead.

So instead of `System.out.println(map)` use this to get a meaningful representation

```
 for(Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : map.entrySet()) {
       System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " -> " + Arrays.toString(entry.getValue()));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method :)

```
     static void print(HashMap<String, String[]> map) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(Map.Entry<String, String[]> e : map.entrySet()) {

            builder.append(e.getKey()).append(" -> [");
            boolean tmp = false;
            for(String s : e.getValue()) {
                if(tmp) {
                    builder.append(" ");
                }
                tmp = true;
                builder.append(s);

            }
            builder.append("]\n");

        }
        System.out.println(builder.toString());

    }
```

You got `[Ljava.lang.String;@90ed2c` because default method toString() for array was invoked.